# A weird observation about Gaussians

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose that $\sigma>0$ and $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be a standard Gaussian random variable. Define
$$
f(\sigma)=P(-1 \leq \sigma N \leq 0).
$$
Clearly $f(0)=1$. However,
$$
f(\sigma)= P(\frac{-1}{\sigma} \leq N \leq 0)=0.5-\Phi(\frac{-1}{\sigma}) \xrightarrow{\sigma \rightarrow 0} 0.5 \neq f(0).
$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the Gaussian CDF. I have double checked if there is anything wrong in the above equalities but it seems a little weird why the above behavior happens, as in why the function $f$ is not continuous at $\sigma=0$.

Comment: "Clearly $f(0)=1$ " And clearly $f(0)=0$ if we had used a strict inequality in the definition. And yet having a $<$ or a $\le$ in the definition doesn't alter your formula for $f(\sigma)$

Comment: This is exactly why one defines the convergence in distribution $X_n\to X$ by the condition that $P(X_n\leqslant x)\to X\leqslant x)$ **at every point $x$ such that $P(X=x)=0$** (and only at these points). In your case,  $X_n=N/n$, $X=0$, $X_n\to0$ almost surely, hence $X_n\to X$ in distributiion, and you simply **disproved** the convergence $P(X_n\leqslant0)\to P(X\leqslant0)$, which is not "weird" in the slightest since $P(X=0)\ne0$.

Comment: *Typo: ...by the condition that $P(X_n\leqslant x)\to P(X\leqslant x)$ at every point such that...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the similar issue with the expression,  $P(\sigma N \leq 0)$.

As long as $\sigma > 0$, $P(\sigma N\leq 0) = .5$, as $N$ is a normal random variable; it can take on both positive and negative values.

But once $\sigma = 0$, $\sigma N$ is now a 'degenerate' random variable; it always equals $0$, so $P(\sigma N \leq 0) = 1$  as it can no longer equal positive values.

Going back to your original question, with some care, you can show that if $\sigma$ is a sufficiently small positive number that $P(\sigma N \leq 0) \approx P(-1 \leq \sigma N \leq 0)$, so the argument above applies.

Comment: Sorry but the OP knows (and explains) all this, no?

Comment: Not at all, this provides an interpretation as to *why* there is a discontinuity.  Once $\sigma = 0$ we no longer have a random process, while if $\sigma > 0$, then the random variable $\sigma N$ is only negative half the time.  (The other answer also integrates this explanation into their answer).

Comment: Rather than pretending that some things were in your answer when I posted my comment, that were not in it, you might try to rewrite your post to reach a more satisfying version. Deal?

Comment: Hopefully the new version is to your liking :).